# Why can't I use a constant int to declare an array AND initialize it in C?

Tags: c

Option 1: use `#define`

```
#define kSize 5
int arr1[kSize] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

--> OK.

Option 2: use an `enum`

```
enum { eSize = 5 };
int arr2[eSize] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

--> OK.

But, a `const int` cannot be used:

```
const int cSize=5;
int arr3[cSize] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

--> FAIL.

why?

Answer (score 4):

A variable with the `const` qualifier does not qualify as an *integer constant expression*.  This makes the array a *variable length array* (VLA) which cannot be initialized.

Section 6.7.6.2p4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) describing Array Declarators states:

> If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type.  If
> the size is `*` instead of being  an  expression,  the  array  type
> is  a variable  length  array type  of  unspecified  size,which can
> only be used in declarations or type names with function prototype
> scope such arrays are nonetheless complete types.  **If the size is an
> integer constant expression and  the  element  type  has  a  known
> constant  size,  the  array  type  is  not  a  variable  length array
> type;**  otherwise,  the  array  type  is  a variable  length  array
> type.   (Variable   length arrays are a conditional feature that
> implementations need not support; see 6.10.8.3.)

So for an array to *not* be a variable length array its size must be an integer constant expression.  This is defined in section 6.6p6:

> An *integer constant  expression* shall  have  integer  type  and  shall
> only  have  operands that   are   integer   constants,   enumeration
> constants,   character   constants, `sizeof` expressions  whose
> results  are  integer  constants, `_Alignof` expressions,  and
> floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts.  Cast
> operators in an integer constant expression  shall  only  convert
> arithmetic  types  to  integer  types,  except  as  part  of  an
> operand to the `sizeof` or `_Alignof` .operator

A `#define` definition is replaced by the preprocessor before the compilation phase, so in your first case `kSize` is *exactly* the same as the constant `5`.  The above passage also states than an enum constant qualifies as an integer constant expression, so this makes your second case OK.  The third case uses a `const` qualified variable which is *not* included above in the definition of an integer constant expression, so this makes it a variable length array.

Section 6.7.9p3 then dictates what can be initialized:

> The  type  of  the  entity  to  be  initialized  shall  be  an  array  of  unknown  size  or  a  complete object type **that is not a variable length array type**.

And as stated above a VLA cannot be initialized.

Comment: Thank you very much for this thorough answer.

Is it just me or does it seem inconsistent that a const int does not make a constant?

Comment: @JeffSzuhay In C++ it would be considered a constant, assuming the initializer was also constant.

Comment: Yes, _that_ makes sense. Now I am wondering why the C committee rejected this carry-back from C++. It just feels quirky in C after so many years programming in C++.